# Predict function returns more values than those required

Tags: r, statistics

My dataset consists of 60 observations in three variables, `x1` and `x2` which are my predictors, and `y` which is my response. The problem is that the last 20 observations in `y` are missing so I fitted a linear regression model, which I called `fit`, onto the first 40 observations and now I have been trying to use the `predict` function to generate the missing values.

The code for the regression I used is

> fit<-lm(y1a~x1a+x2a)

where y1a,x1a and x2a refer to the first 40 observations.

The code I have been using to fill in the remaining values is:

```
x <- data.frame(data$x1[41:60], data$x2[41:60])

predict(fit,x,interval="prediction",level=0.95)
```

But now the problem is that I get 40 new values for `y` instead of the required 20, along with the warning message:

> 'newdata' had 20 rows but variables found have 40 rows

Could you please tell me what I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The column names of the data frame sent to `predict` must match the column names of the data frame used to create the model. If you create `x` as you show above the names will not be the same and `predict` will instead use the original data (the frame you call `data`).

Try this instead

```
fit <- lm(y ~ ., data[1:40,])
predict(fit, data[41:60,])
```

Comment: I have included the code you requested in my question.

Comment: Thanks! This is a very common problem that has been answered many many times on SO. Unfortunately people usually approach it from different angles and do not realize it is the same fundamental problem. I found it very confusing too at first.